# Split excel cell into different rows in GUI

Tags: excel, split, cell

I have an excel file which contains something like this:

[image: An excel file with such a row]

I have a running python script which creates a User GUI. The GUI lists the "Description" column from the excel as a single line in the GUI. I would like to have new lines after each semicolon ";" in the Description. i.e

Current output:

[image: Current Output]

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]
[Expected output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kfnM.png)

Comment: Do you want separate line in same cell or each line in each cell?

Comment: If you are looking for help in Python, I think you should add the proper tag and the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `FILTERXML()`

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

More about [FILTERXML()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747)

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun, i guess this is not what i want. I dont want the seperated result in Excel but in the GUI.